# How can I Insert Data Into a Join Table with a Many to Many Relation Using a Rails Controller Page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given: 2 Tables, Lists, and Cars, which have many to many relations.

I want to append it with data from console. Finding and reading it from the browser works, but how can I add and append through the rails controller page?

Answer (score 1):

With any has_many relationship you can add a record with <<

```
@car.lists << @list
@list.cars << @car
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in your cad controller:

```
lists = List.where(id:params[:lists])
@cars.assign_attributes({lists: lists})
```

Comment: the problem now that it insert a new row in the cars table and then add it to the join table, but what i need is to select a car and select a list and just add the two ids in the join table

Comment: first you find car with help of car id and then find the list with the help of list id then assign val like this